# Reference for Fukaya Categories and Homological Mirror Symmetry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, mathematical-physics, mirror-symmetry

What references are there for learning Fukaya categories (specifically, good references for self-study)?

In addition, any references with an eye toward homological mirror symmetry would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A google search yielded this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7056

Comment: Yes, I have that as well as some other references in my que.  Perhaps I should be a bit more clear: I am asking if anyone personally recommends references that they have read on the subject that they find to be good introductions (especially for self-study), in order to whittle down the references I have to a few good ones.  :)

Comment: are you interested in the geoemtry behind them, or in the $A_\infty$-category structure?

Comment: Well, I do try to have a geometric understanding of anything I can… but I personally gravitate more towards anything (higher) category-theortic, so I suppose it would be the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally recommend Paul Seidel's [Fukaya Categories and Picard-Lefschetz Theory](https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=12)
book. It is not easy (imho) but contains an introduction to $A_\infty$-categories, it explains the Fukaya categories in both a preliminary and a complete version and provides an example of Fukaya cat. of a Lefschetz fibration.

Another good reference is the paper

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0011041.pdf

Section 4 is about $A_\infty$-structures, while section5 contains an introduction to Fukaya categories.

Comment: Good to know that Konstevich's paper is good, since I was planning on reading through it no matter what!  :D

I'll have to head over to the library and check out Seidel's book tomorrow -- thanks!  Much appreciated.